# Are we supposed to say 'Alaihi Salam' on any Prophet's name during recitation of the Quran?

Tags: prophets, quran-recitation, salawat

Are we supposed to say 'Alaihi Salam' during recitation when the name of any prophet is mentioned in Quran?

Will we be sinful if we dont say alaihi salam?

Answer (score 1):

While reciting the Holy Quran, it is not necessary to say Alayhi salam. No one becomes sinful if he doesn't say AlaihiSalam

Answer (score 0):

When reciting the Qur'an, if we reach the blessed name of the beloved Prophet of God, Hazrat Muhammad Mustafa, peace be upon him and his family, let us send blessings.